# Python: advapi32.SetServiceStatus() fails with error 6

Tags: python, windows, service, ffi

Original issue is now resolved, many thanks to eryksun.

Fixed code is below, I now have a different issue that I will ask about in another thread if I cannot figure it out.

Error 6 is invalid handle, however, the handle appears to be good, I believe the error is coming from the second parameter.

```
        status = advapi32.SetServiceStatus(g_hServiceStatus, pointer(m_oServiceStatus))
        if 0 == status:
            dwStatus = winKernel.GetLastError()
```

Note: if I make the pointer None, then it doesn't fail (but obviously doesn't do anything useful either).

> python -V
>
> Python 3.6.6

Larger snippet:

```
from ctypes import *
from ctypes.wintypes import *

winKernel = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32', use_last_error=True)
advapi32 = ctypes.WinDLL('advapi32', use_last_error=True)

global g_ServiceName
g_ServiceName = "StatusMonitor"

global g_lpcstrServiceName
g_lpcstrServiceName = LPCSTR(b"StatusMonitor")

class _SERVICE_STATUS(Structure):
    _pack_ = 4
    _fields_ = [
        ("dwServiceType", DWORD),
        ("dwCurrentState", DWORD),
        ("dwControlsAccepted", DWORD),
        ("dwWin32ExitCode", DWORD),
        ("dwServiceSpecificExitCode", DWORD),
        ("dwCheckPoint", DWORD),
        ("dwWaitHint", DWORD)
        ]

LPSERVICE_STATUS = POINTER(_SERVICE_STATUS)


global m_oServiceStatus
m_oServiceStatus = _SERVICE_STATUS(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)

global g_hServiceStatus
g_hServiceStatus = SERVICE_STATUS_HANDLE(None)

<lots of code snipped>

def status_report(dwCurrentState, dwWin32ExitCode, dwWaitHint):
    global g_dwCheckPoint
    global g_isService

    try:

        # Fill in the SERVICE_STATUS structure.

        m_oServiceStatus.dwServiceType = SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS
        m_oServiceStatus.dwCurrentState = dwCurrentState
        m_oServiceStatus.dwWin32ExitCode = dwWin32ExitCode
        m_oServiceStatus.dwWaitHint = dwWaitHint

        if dwCurrentState == SERVICE_START_PENDING:
            m_oServiceStatus.dwControlsAccepted = 0
        else:
            m_oServiceStatus.dwControlsAccepted = 1

        if (dwCurrentState == SERVICE_STOPPED) or (dwCurrentState == SERVICE_RUNNING):
            m_oServiceStatus.dwCheckPoint = 0
        else:
            g_dwCheckPoint += 1
            m_oServiceStatus.dwCheckPoint = g_dwCheckPoint

            status = advapi32.SetServiceStatus(g_hServiceStatus, pointer(m_oServiceStatus))
            if 0 == status:
                dwStatus = winKernel.GetLastError()
                #logging.info("SetServiceStatus(" + str(g_hServiceStatus) + ", status=" + str(dwStatus) + ")")

        logging.info("status_report(" + str(g_hServiceStatus) + ", " + str(dwCurrentState) + ", " + str(dwWin32ExitCode) + ", " + str(dwWaitHint) + ")")

    dwStatus = None
    if g_isService:
        # Report the status of the service to the SCM.
        ptrServiceStatus = LPSERVICE_STATUS(m_oServiceStatus)
        logging.info("m_oServiceStatus struct: " + str(m_oServiceStatus) + ", ref: " + str(byref(m_oServiceStatus)))
        logging.info("                         " + "ptr: " + str(str(pointer(m_oServiceStatus))) + " PTR: " + str(ptrServiceStatus))

        advapi32.SetServiceStatus.restype = BOOL
        advapi32.SetServiceStatus.argtypes = [SERVICE_STATUS_HANDLE, LPSERVICE_STATUS]
        status = advapi32.SetServiceStatus(g_hServiceStatus, ptrServiceStatus)
        if 0 == status:
            dwStatus = ctypes.get_last_error()

    except Exception as e:
        exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
        logging.error("status_report " + str(e) + " line: " + str(exc_tb.tb_lineno))

    return dwStatus


    advapi32.RegisterServiceCtrlHandlerExA.restype = SERVICE_STATUS_HANDLE
    advapi32.RegisterServiceCtrlHandlerExA.argtypes = [LPCSTR, LPHANDLER_FUNCTION_EX, LPVOID]
    g_hServiceStatus = advapi32.RegisterServiceCtrlHandlerExA(g_lpcstrServiceName, LPHANDLER_FUNCTION_EX(svc_control_handler_ex), LPVOID(None))
    logging.info("control handler " + str(g_hServiceStatus))

    logging.info("control handler called count " + str(g_nServiceControlHandlerCalled))

    m_oServiceStatus.dwServiceType = SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS;
    m_oServiceStatus.dwServiceSpecificExitCode = 0;

    # set the service state as pending
    dwStatus = status_report(SERVICE_START_PENDING, NO_ERROR, 3000);
    logging.info("service_main: status_report(" + str(g_hServiceStatus) + "), status=" + str(dwStatus))
    log_service_status(m_oServiceStatus)
```

Updated logging result:

```
INFO    service_start
INFO    service_start: StopEventHandle 952
INFO    service_main called JimsStatusMonitor control handler called count 0
INFO    control handler 2787686645712
INFO    control handler called count 0
INFO    status_report(2787686645712, 2, 0, 3000)128
INFO    m_oServiceStatus struct: <__main__._SERVICE_STATUS object at 0x000002890FC666C8>, ref: <cparam 'P' (000002890FCA8A30)>
INFO                             ptr: <__main__.LP__SERVICE_STATUS object at 0x000002890FC66848> PTR: <__main__.LP__SERVICE_STATUS object at 0x000002890FC66648>
INFO    service_main: status_report(2787686645712), status=None
INFO        16, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3000
```

I must be missing something obvious, but I don't see it. I tried different *pack* to the structure, but with no improvement.

I also tried using byref() instead of pointer() and just passing the structure, but none of those worked.  I believe using pointer() is correct here because there is another API to set the dispatch table that is working using pointer().

Note that I am specifically using FFI for this as I found the existing packages lacking for what I am trying to do.  This Python solution is based on a C++ solution that I wrote that works, I just need to understand whatever nuance to the FFI that is causing it to fail.

I should add that the service is actually running at this point, I just can't transition it out of Starting state with this issue.

Hopefully someone can tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance,
-Dave

Comment: Use `advapi32 = ctypes.WinDLL('advapi32', use_last_error=True)` and `ctypes.get_last_error()` instead of `GetLastError()`. It's more reliable.

Comment: Assuming that `SERVICE_STATUS_HANDLE` is an opaque pointer type, you must set `advapi32.RegisterServiceCtrlHandlerExA.restype = SERVICE_STATUS_HANDLE`. If it's a simple ctypes pointer (e.g. `c_void_p`), then you must either manually wrap the result as a pointer instance (e.g. `result = c_void_p(result)`) to get around the automatic integer conversion, or else set `argtypes` for all functions that use the pointer. That said, you should be setting the full prototype for all FFI functions anyway. Type safety is extremely important with ctypes code.

Comment: Also, it's pointless to set  `g_hServiceStatus = SERVICE_STATUS_HANDLE(None)` and subsequently assign `g_hServiceStatus = advapi32.RegisterServiceCtrlHandlerExA(...)` in the same scope. It's also redundant to declare `global g_hServiceStatus` at module scope; they're the same scope.

Comment: SERVICE_STATUS_HANDLE is defined in wintypes.py, so I wouldn't have thought I would need to do anything different with that?  I have only defined the things that are not defined there.  I am trying some of your suggestions, will update...

Comment: `ctypes.wintypes.SERVICE_STATUS_HANDLE` is an alias for `ctypes.c_void_p`. This is a simple pointer type, so when it's set as a function's `restype`, the return value is automatically converted to a Python integer. If you pass this integer to a function without setting the type in `argtypes`, the default conversion is to a 32-bit `c_int`, which will truncate the upper 32-bit part of the pointer value if you're using 64-bit Python. Similarly, if you don't set `restype` at all, the result type also defaults to 32-bit `c_int`.

Comment: Only kernel handles (e.g. job, process, thread, section, file, event, semaphore) and user handles (e.g. `HWND`) are guaranteed to fit in a 32-bit value. Other 'handles' used in the OS are actually pointers, such as an `HMODULE` for the base address of a loaded DLL, and must be 64-bit values in a 64-bit process.

Comment: Thanks for all of the commentary!  I will update the example, it is now getting much further.  I think I have an issue with setting up the dispatcher, I will describe the new issue once I update the code.

Comment: eryksun, I want to mark this as answered, but I don't want to answer it myself, how do I give you the credit?

Comment: I'd write up an answer if I had something new to say on the matter. But I've answered similar questions before. After you've fixed up your code and have gained some insight into the problem, take the time to search for similar/duplicate questions.

Comment: I spent a day looking, I was just looking for the wrong things. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

With many thanks to eryksun, I was able to resolve the original issue.

The main issue was that I was assuming the Windows APIs were fully defined because it seemed like they were working without restype and argstype defined.

Needed the following:

```
advapi32.RegisterServiceCtrlHandlerExA.restype = SERVICE_STATUS_HANDLE
advapi32.RegisterServiceCtrlHandlerExA.argtypes = [LPCSTR, LPHANDLER_FUNCTION_EX, LPVOID]
g_hServiceStatus = advapi32.RegisterServiceCtrlHandlerExA(g_lpcstrServiceName, LPHANDLER_FUNCTION_EX(svc_control_handler_ex), LPVOID(None))

advapi32.SetServiceStatus.restype = BOOL
advapi32.SetServiceStatus.argtypes = [SERVICE_STATUS_HANDLE, LPSERVICE_STATUS]
status = advapi32.SetServiceStatus(g_hServiceStatus, ptrServiceStatus)
```

With those defined correctly, there were still two remaining issues that I was able to figure out from the documentation.

The first was I missed that restype is the first argument to WINFUNCTYPE(), given the responses from eryksun, it was more obvious to me, and that explained why my definition for my service_main() wasn't working as expected.

The second was a bit more subtle and is found at the end of the callback documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2.5/lib/ctypes-callback-functions.html):

> **Important note for callback functions:**
>
> Make sure you keep references to CFUNCTYPE objects as long as they are
>   used from C code. ctypes doesn't, and if you don't, they may be
>   garbage collected, crashing your program when a callback is made.

Note that the original code that was failing can be found in the Python forum [here](https://python-forum.io/Thread-advapi32-SetServiceStatus-fails-with-error-6?pid=64045#pid64045).